# Sprite kit constrain node movement on a grid

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit, what is the best way to constrain a node movement only on grid lines?

In my game, I have a 5x5 grid and a node which is randomly placed on one of the grid's intersection. User can move this node by finger anywhere on the grid but it has to follow the grid's axis line, which means that only vertical or horizontal movement is allowed at any time.

I've new to SpriteKit and not sure if there are some mechanisms that are provided by SpriteKit framework or I will have to manually constrain the node movement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a grid based solution from GameplayKit: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html

With that and a from-scratch algorithm to to calculate the direction of the movement for swipe/drag direction you can achieve the solution :)